# Is it possible to use the argument=value syntax to take a list of inputs in argparse using nargs="+"?

Tags: argparse

You can define an argument along the lines of:

```
parser.add_argument('--arg', nargs='+')
```

You can then parse arguments of the form `--arg 1 2 3` and you'll get a list of `['1', '2', '3']` out.

You can parse arguments in an alternative style of `argument=value`. This works fine for an argument that takes a single input.

How can you do the same for arguments where `nargs` is greater than 1?

Parsing `--arg=1 2 3` fails because it parses as "arg" with a value of "1", and two separate arguments 2 and 3, which are (understandably) not recognised.

Parsing `--arg=1,2,3` (understandably) gives a list with a single value: `['1,2,3']`.

I know I could just take a single string input and split it on "," myself instead of using `nargs="+"`, however it would then not work in the `--arg 1 2 3` case. Also, I'd like to do less of it myself, and have the library take care of more of it for me. Particularly given I'm also going to convert them to ints, so want to make use of `type=int`.

Comment: No you can't mix the `=` and multiple `nargs` forms.  Parsing handles them in different ways.

Comment: `parser.parse_known_args('--arg=1 2'.split())` returns `(Namespace(arg=['1']), ['2'])`.  The `=` has priority in determining how many arguments `arg` gets.  Anything else is put in the unrecognized extras.